# Access event.state from history.pushState outside of popstate event

Tags: javascript, popstate

I am trying to compare the popstate event's **new url** with the **last visited URL that was in the window** of the user.

I thought this would be simple using event.state, but I can only seem to access this object from inside onpopstate and nothing else. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but scouring documentation for 3 days redeems nothing.

Quite simple what I'm trying to do:

```
    console.log(event.state);

    window.addEventListener( 'popstate', function(event) { 
            if(event.state){
                console.log(event.state);
            }
    }, false );
```

I am using history.pushState and history.replaceState to set the event object at various places, but again, would like to get this object anywhere I want to access it's data.

Comment: have you tried storing it in a variable?

Comment: How would I store the variable outside of the popstate?

Comment: define a variable outside, then inside the popstate set the value of `event.state` to the variable and use it outside of the function

Comment: Thanks, combining your suggestion with an array inside an object and unshift I have managed to build a solution. If you would like to post your comment as a reply I can tag it as an answer.

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but it is more of a comment, I'd rather not to post it as an answer

Comment: May it help:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#Adding_and_modifying_history_entries